# Estimating a linear probability model on a subsample

Tags: econometrics, binary-data

I am dealing with a situation where I have a binary outcome variable $z \in \{0,1\}$ for treatment under a program that ran from 2000 to 2010 (so units were treated throughout the period). In my data, I have:

1. Some units that were treated before the program started ($z_{it} = 1$ from 2000 to 2010)
2. Some units that were treated between 2000 and 2005 ($z_{it}$ changes from $0$ to $1$ between 2000 and 2005).
3. Some units that were treated between 2005 and 2010 ($z_{it}$ changes from $0$ to $1$ between 2005 and 2010).

Once treated, a unit remains so for all remaining periods.

I estimate the linear probability model (probability of being treated):

\begin{equation}
z_{it} = x'_{it}\beta + \nu_{it}
\end{equation}

Abstracting from the standard shortcomings of the model ($x'_i\beta$ can be outside $0$ and $1$), suppose I want to estimate the model in two subsamples, 2000 - 2005 and 2005 - 2010, separately. Is it statistically valid to split the sample into those treated before 2005 and those treated after 2005 and estimate the equation above on each subsample? I can deal with (1) by dropping these observations, but I am not sure if (2) and (3) would bias the estimates.

I don't know if this would be relevant, but the predicted values would be used in the second stage of a two-stage approach.

If you have any ideas, or can point to any notes or articles on this point, it would be a great help.

Thank you.